# React single selectable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying to make a selection button where only a single item can be selected and it deselects the other items. I have made it as far as selecting an item, but not the deselecting the other items part.

Below is my component code :

```
class Diamond extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selectDiamond = this.selectDiamond.bind(this);
    this.state = {selected : false};
  }

  selectDiamond() {
    this.setState( {selected : true} );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.selected == true) {
      return (
        <div onClick={this.selectDiamond} className="diamond-selected hover:scale-[105%] duration-300 ">{this.props.text}</div>
      )
    } else {
      return(
        <div onClick={this.selectDiamond} className="diamond-unselected hover:scale-[105%] duration-300 ">{this.props.text}</div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

and this is how I render it :

```
<div>
    {["BOY", "GIRL", "BAKLA", "TOMBOY"].map((item, i) => (
        <Diamond key={i} text={item}/>
        )
    )}
</div>
```

I know I need a reference to the `<Diamond/>`s so I tried something like :

```
let diamonds = [];

//and on the constructor method of the component 
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   diamonds.push(this);
}
```

but for some reason when I call `diamonds.length` it gives me double the number of the created items, and I also do not know what to do from there. I also would like the first item to be selected by default.

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend using hooks instead of class components.
Here is snippet how it can be done:

```
const Diamond = ({ text, setSelected, isSelected }) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={setSelected}
      className={`diamond-${
        isSelected ? "" : "un"
      }selected hover:scale-[105%] duration-300`}
    >
      {text}
    </div>
  );
};

const ListDiamonds = () => {
  const [selectedIdx, setSelectedIdx] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      {["BOY", "GIRL", "BAKLA", "TOMBOY"].map((item, i) => (
        <Diamond
          key={i}
          text={item}
          isSelected={selectedIdx === i}
          setSelected={() => setSelectedIdx(i)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I did not test it but in general concept it like that.

Also do not push `this` from constructor, it is bad practice.
You could read rect lifting state up: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html
or better with hooks: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-lifting-state-up-in-react/